# Sending output of a java program with methods to file

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have a program that I already created in Java that has several methods that ask for user input.

This is the program:

```
static Scanner numberscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
static Integer[] houses = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    askForCrates();
    getTotal();
    int max = houses[0];
    getMin();
    getMaxHouse(max);
    //Display the house number that recycled the most
}


//asks for the crates for each specific house number
public static void askForCrates()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("How many crates does house " + i + " have?") ;
        Integer crates = numberscanner.nextInt();
        houses[i] = crates;
    }
}

//uses a for statement to get the total of all the crates recycled
public static void getTotal()
{
    //Get total
    Integer total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
    {
        total = total + houses[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Total amount of recycling crates is: " + total);
}

//Displays and returns the max number of crates
public static Integer getMax(Integer max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
    {
        if(houses[i] > max)
        {
            max = houses[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest number of crates set out: " + max);
    return max;
}

// gets the house numbers that recycled the most
// and puts them in a string
public static void getMaxHouse(Integer max)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> besthouses = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String bhs = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
    {
        if(houses[i].equals(max))
        {
            besthouses.add(houses[i]);
        }
    }
    for (Integer s : besthouses)
    {
         bhs += s + ", ";
    }
    System.out.println("The house(s) that recycled " + max + " crates were: " + bhs.substring(0, bhs.length()-2));
}

// gets the minimum using the Arrays function to sort the
// array
public static void getMin()
{
    //Find the smallest number of crates set out by any house

    Arrays.sort(houses);
    int min = houses[0];
    System.out.println("Smallest number of crates set out: " + min);
}
}   // probably the closing '}' of the class --- added by editor
```

The program works fine but now I want to take all the output including the users input and put that output into a file.

I've seen ways to do this with `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter` and I understand how those work with the input and output using the reader.

Except in the example programs I have seen, none of those programs have methods.

I can rewrite my program without methods or modify them to return input instead of being void and using `System.println`. But I was wondering if there is a way to send all the output of my program to a file without having to rewrite my program?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, you can run your program as:

```
java -jar app.jar >> log.out
```

Edit for the correct way:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("log.out");
PrintStream orig = System.out;
System.setOut(ps);
```

And don't forget:

```
ps.close();
```

in the end